# How do I use C preprocessor macros with Rust's FFI?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, ffi, rust

I'm writing some code that interfaces an existing library written in C. In my Rust code I'd like to be able to use values from CPP macros. If I have a C include.h that looks like this:

```
#define INIT_FLAG 0x00000001
```

I'd like to be able to use it in Rust like this:

```
#[link(name="mylib")]
extern {
    pub static init_flag: c_int = INIT_FLAG;
}
```

I've looked at other FFI code and I see a lot of people
duplicating these values in Rust instead of getting them from the FFI.
This seems a little brittle, and I'd also like to be able to handle
more complicated things that are defined via CPP macros.
Running `cpp` over my Rust files would only work if I'm sure my
CPP macros are only used for simple things.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is impossible, and I don't think it will be possible in the future. C macros bring too many problems with them. If you want to run `cpp` over your Rust sources, you can do it manually.

If you don't want to do it and if there is a lot of constants and you also don't want to copy their values from C code to Rust you can make a C wrapper which will provide global variables with these values:

```c
#define INIT_FLAG 0x00000001

...

const int init_flag = INIT_FLAG;
```

You compile this file, create a static library from it and link to it as usual:

```
$ gcc -c init_flag.c
$ ar r libinitflag.a init_flag.o
```

Rust source:

```rust
use std::libc;

#[link(name="initflag", kind="static")]
extern {
    pub static init_flag: libc::c_int;
}
```

Rust source is nearly identical to what you tried to achieve. You will need C glue object file, however.

Comment: i tried doing this, using build.rs and cc::Build::new() but it doesnt seem to like the way the linker works. all the -L and -l flags look ok but it has undefined reference at linktime to the static variable.

Comment: you probly need to change the code to `extern const int` as `const int`s are private

Comment: @xcvr not sure what do you mean. In C, all items are exposed in the object file unless they are marked with `static`. `extern` is only needed to reference *other* items from C code, it is not needed to "export" anything since without `static` all items are "exported".

Comment: My mistake. This is one of the places where C++ differs from C.

Answer (score 4):

That's merely impossible because a C macro constant doesn't represent any object or entity at runtime. That's because the `cpp` preprocessor performs macro expansion (and handles the rest directives) even before compilation takes place. Consider the following snippet:

```
#define INIT_FLAG 0x00000001

/* some code */

unsigned dummy() { return INIT_FLAG; }

/* some other code */
```

Running `cpp` on the snippet yields preprocessed code (so called *compilation unit*, or *translation unit*) which has all occurences of `INIT_FLAG` replaced by the literal `0x00000001`:

```
unsigned dummy() { return 0x00000001; }
```

The compilation unit then gets compiled, resulting in the object file, but now there's no trace of `INIT_FLAG` in it. Therefore, you cannot refer to `INIT_FLAG` when linking against the object file: it simply doesn't contain such symbol.